# Understanding Ajax Simplifications in Spring 3.0 example

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to understand the Spring example at http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/.

I have a questions to clear up some of my concerns:

Question 1:

At $.getJSON("account/availability",.... are they passing an object account and calling the RequestMapping availability?

```
function checkAvailability() {
    $.getJSON("account/availability", { name: $('#name').val() }, function(availability) {
        if (availability.available) {
            fieldValidated("name", { valid : true });
        } else {
            fieldValidated("name", { valid : false,
                message : $('#name').val() + " is not available, try " + availability.suggestions });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a full picture, here is the controller handling the request:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/availability", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody AvailabilityStatus getAvailability(@RequestParam String name) {
```

[`@RequestParam`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) annotation is crucial. It:

> indicates that a method parameter should be bound to a web request parameter

Now when caling:

```
$.getJSON("account/availability", { name: $('#name').val() }
```

jQuery will issue GET request to the following URI: `account/availability?name=foo`. The `@RequestParam` annotation on the server side will extract the `name` parameter and inject it, so that `name` argument in your controller is equal to `"foo"`.

UPDATE:

With regards to `/account` part of the URI, it is not mentioned in the original article, but it seems like the handler method above is placed in a controller with similar declaration:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountController {
```

When request to `/account/availability` hits the server, Spring MVC first finds the controller matching the beginning of the URI (`/account`) and then looks for a method matching the remaining part (`/availability`). Sadly this part is not explained in the article, maybe you can ask the author to update it?

Comment: what is the function availability.available about is this an java object?

Comment: so what youre saying is that 'account' is part of the URI, but how come the controller value is just '/availability'?

Comment: you still havent answered my question as to what is the 'account' part of the uri about

Comment: @dev_darin: see my update, I explained how URI matching works.

Comment: thank you very much for making this clearer. So what you're saying is you can actually make a call to two separate methods this way from your view? If this is so i think its pretty cool